# Change background color of the checkbox which looks like a button when checked

Tags: html, css, button, checkbox

I am trying to create a checkbox which looks like a button, I am able to get it done but the only problem I am having is I am not able to change the background color of the button when it's checked. Currently when I check the checkbox the button becomes light- grey I want it to be blue, here is the snippet of my HTML and CSS. Any help is appreciated, Thanks in advance

```css
.checkboxes{
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 90;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Arial";
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #235988;
  width: 270px;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 0px !important;
  border: 1px solid #235988 !important;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
 }

 .checkboxes:hover{
   background: #235988 !important;
   color: #FFF !important;
  }

  .form-check label input[type="checkbox"]:checked{
    background: #235988;
    color: #FFF;
  }


.form-check label input[type="checkbox"] {
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12 form-check list-inline list-group-horizontal btn-group" role="group" data-toggle="buttons">
<label for="checkbox_select" class="col-md-3"> Please select one or many checkboxes </label>
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <label class="btn btn-default checkboxes">
          <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_select" value = "1" class = "form-check list-group-item" id = "checkbox_select0" >  Checkbox1
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-default checkboxes">
          <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_select" value = "2" class = "form-check list-group-item" id = "checkbox_select1" >  Checkbox2
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-default checkboxes">
          <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_select" value = "3" class = "form-check list-group-item" id = "checkbox_select2" >  Checkbox3
        </label>
</div>
```

Comment: It may be useful for you https://jsfiddle.net/kohansalism/w4u8tdca/

Comment: This doesn't work for me as the label consist of the class btn-default even i add !important it does not overwrite. with the fiddel it only wraps the text span in blue color for me but not the button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put your input outside the label as a sibling (since we will use the [Adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) ) and use the ["for" attributer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label#using_the_for_attribute)

```css
.checkboxes{
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 90;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Arial";
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #235988;
  width: 270px;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 0px !important;
  border: 1px solid #235988 !important;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
 }

.checkboxes:hover,
  .form-check input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label{
    background: #235988;
    color: #FFF;
  }


.form-check input[type="checkbox"] {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12 form-check list-inline list-group-horizontal btn-group" role="group" data-toggle="buttons">
<label for="checkbox_select" class="col-md-3"> Please select one or many checkboxes </label>
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <input id="checkbox-1" type="checkbox" name="checkbox_select" value = "1" class = "form-check list-group-item" id = "checkbox_select0" >
        <label class="btn btn-default checkboxes" for="checkbox-1">
            Checkbox1
        </label>
        <input id="checkbox-2" type="checkbox" name="checkbox_select" value = "2" class = "form-check list-group-item" id = "checkbox_select1" >
        <label class="btn btn-default checkboxes" for="checkbox-2">
            Checkbox2
        </label>
         <input id="checkbox-3" type="checkbox" name="checkbox_select" value = "3" class = "form-check list-group-item" id = "checkbox_select2" >
        <label class="btn btn-default checkboxes" for="checkbox-3">
           Checkbox3
        </label>
</div>
```

Comment: When I tried this, I am not able to check the checkbox at all, can only hover it but when I click it , it does not get selected. I made sure to use the for attributor with label and linked it with checkbox id but still the same

Comment: @MohammedSayer can you provide a link to your fiddle or webpage where it is not working?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are many solutions.
I introduce you just one of them.

1. Hide the iuput by setting css display property none.
2. Make a toggle button looks you like as span or div element.
3. Attach js function on div element onclick attrbute.  Function toggles option of hidden iuput element.

But Ithink more ez way is to use some flamework, like Vue,Angular,and so on.

Comment: I want to do it using css